# Load a href="#" tag using selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am scraping a page using selenium. But all the information that I need can not be loaded at first on the chrome driver, and I need to click on a tag "a"
 Show more matches

I have tried many solutions to load this tag: finding by tag name, XPath,... but there is an error : Element ... is not clickable at point (499, 800).

I also tried to use the javascript to load this. it used to work but recently there some updates on the website and this also doesn't work.
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) archiveDriver;
          js.executeScript("return cjs.Api.loader.get('cjs').call(function(_cjs){loadMoreGames(_cjs);});");

any idea how can apply a click or load the rest of the data on the page?